# I am getting a live in my earth of my extension cord socket

Tags: power-supply, socket

I am getting a live connection in my earth port of my extension cord socket. I opened up it and I am seeing this. Please help me find what is the issue. 
[image: img]

Comment: What is the green thing between yellow and red wire? Anyway, i would not touch that with a six-foot pole.

Comment: I thought the green was earth but then what's yellow? Looks safe doesn't it! I'd wonder if earth in the main mains socket is wired up at all and how he knows earth is live. Got a shock maybe?

Comment: @venny Yeah I also found that strange. I think it is a capacitor . But no idea y it Is there ? Should I take it out ?

Comment: @carveone I  put a tester in the earth port and found tat it's live.

Comment: These are cheap enough that you should get a new one instead of risking your life trying to repair it. Also are you sure that the voltage presence on the ground conductor isn't also present at the mains socket? The outlet strip might be just fine.

Comment: @carveone the wiring is fine from the main socket even though the wire colours are messed up. Grey is live, green is ground and blue is neutral.  The green stuff is the issue. But am no electrical geek so need u guys help to understand this mess.

Comment: @JYelton the voltage presence on the ground  is not present at the main socket . And as u said I will have to throw this out lol. But am just curious about the green capacitor between live and ground.

Comment: the green thingy might be a surge protector of some sort and one of them probably failed resulting in a short circuit. unless you are extra sure about how to repair the device please **throw it away and buy a new one**. Your health is **priceless**.

Comment: Ah I see it now - it's a MOV or TVS. Surge surpressor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector). Totally agree with Vladimir. The MOV likely shorted so throw it away. Possible also check your house wiring to see why something didn't trip in the fuse board.

Comment: Hmm I will have to check my home connection to see y it was not tripping. Thanks a lot guys . I will throw this thing away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the earth connection is broken somewhere and those parts (MOVs or Capacitors) are leaking or conducting a bit of current to the 'earth' pin on the power bar sockets. One of them could also have failed short, but you would not see any difference with a voltmeter. In any case that current should be conducted out to the earth terminal on the cord and either the voltage from leakage would be close to zero or a fuse would blow. So either there are two faults (unlikely, but possible) or the earth wire on your power bar/wall socket has a break somewhere.

Check it with an ohmmeter from the far end socket (yellow wire) to the ground pin on the plug. It should read the same as if you short the wires on the ohmmeter (less than 1 ohm). It could be broken in the cord where it is not very visible (likely right by the plug or right by where it exits the power bar (at the strain relief).

It's also possible that your power bar is as okay as it ever was (!) but the wall socket has no solid earth connection, in which case you should have that fixed as soon as possible. For that reason I suggest troubleshooting this power bar (then throw it away).

Comment: I've opened wall sockets and found no earth connection at all. I think this question has a certain amount of merit just for the reasons you say - to safety check his wall socket.

Comment: @carveone I've heard of 'handyman' additions such as inlaw/rental units (constructed sans proper building permits and inspections) that wired outlets to hidden extension cords (3-wire or maybe two wire).